# MySQL TRIM SELECT result output

Tags: mysql, sql, select, trim

I have following `MySQL` query result, I want only UserName first part before `@` it need `10000013` part only,  I want to remove `example.com` part, it is possible by TRIM?

```
mysql> SELECT UserName,DAY(AcctStartTime), COUNT(ResponseCode='200') FROM table201412 WHERE UserName='10000013@example.com' GROUP BY DATE(AcctStartTime);
+---------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+
| UserName                  | DAY(AcctStartTime) | COUNT(ResponseCode='200') |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+
| 10000013@example.com |                  1 |                            3 |
| 10000013@example.com |                  2 |                            5 |
| 10000013@example.com |                  3 |                            3 |
+----------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need following result:

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+
| UserName                  | DAY(AcctStartTime) | COUNT(ResponseCode='200') |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+
| 10000013                  |                  1 |                            3 |
| 10000013                  |                  2 |                            5 |
| 10000013                  |                  3 |                            3 |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: If you'd bothered to [RTFM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) you'd see that no, you can't use `trim()` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(UserName, '@', 1) as EmailName
```

In your query, that would be:

```
SELECT substring_index(UserName, '@', 1) as EmailName, DAY(AcctStartTime), COUNT(ResponseCode='200')
FROM table201412
WHERE UserName='10000013@example.com'
GROUP BY DATE(AcctStartTime);
```